# How to test a Python Sudoku Class

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing basic tests for my Sudoku checker but I am having an issue with it testing. I am not sure what is going on. If I'm supposed to return something. I really do not know. Please help thank you.

```
class Sudoku_Checker(object):
  def __init__(self,board):
    self.board = board

  def board_validater():
    checkRows(self.board)
    checkCols(self.board)
    checkSquares(self.board)

    return checkRows() == True and checkCols() == True and checkSquares() == True

  # def checkRows:
  #
  # def checkCols:
  #
  # def checkSquares:
```

Here are the tests I wrote. When ever I run them in my terminal, it just says "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s". I do not know why it is not working.

```
from ValidSudoku import *

class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):
    def willWork(self):
        """
        Check to return True
        """
        grid = [  [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
          [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
          [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
          [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
          [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
          [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
          [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
          [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
          [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]]
        result = Sudoku_Checker.board_validater(grid)
        self.assertTrue(result)

    def willWork2(self):
        """
        Check to return False
        """
        grid = [
          [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
          [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3, 4, 8],
          [1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0],
          [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0],
          [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
          [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
          [9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4],
          [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
          [3, 0, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 9]
        ]
        result = Sudoku_Checker.board_validater(grid)
        self.assertFalse(result)
```

Comment: You should name test methods in TestSum class with "test" prefix like "testWillWork2". Please read the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

Comment: Thank you I will check it out. I wish you posted it as an answer so I could have given you points. I'm debugging now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the names of methods in TestSum class

```py
    def willWork(self):
```

To

```py
    def testWillWork(self):
```

You can find more info in greatly written Python documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html